# sequelize adding field in where clause in top level

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm having a query like this:

```
const { count, rows: questions } = await QBQuestion.findAndCountAll({
  where: {
    [Sequelize.Op.or]: [
      { 'QBQuestionSkills.Skill.Skill': { [Sequelize.Op.substring]: 'python' } }, { Text: { [Sequelize.Op.substring]: keyWord } }
    ]
  },
  limit,
  offset,
  include: [
     {},...{}, //Few Joins redacted here
    {
      model: sequelize.models.QBQuestionSkill,
      required: false,
      as: 'QBQuestionSkills',
      include: [
        {
          model: sequelize.models.Skill,
          as: 'Skill',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  attributes:
    ['Id', 'Text', 'DomainId', 'SubdomainId', 'TotalAnswerTime', 'McqAnswerId', 'FileId', 'Difficulty', 'SchemaId'],
  order: [['Id', 'DESC']],
});
```

This above forms query of this type (Count part):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(`QBQuestion`.`Id`) AS `count`
FROM
    `QBQuestion` AS `QBQuestion`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `QuestionType` AS `QuestionType`
ON
    `QBQuestion`.`QuestionTypeId` = `QuestionType`.`QuestionTypeId`
INNER JOIN `AnswerType` AS `AnswerType`
ON
    `QBQuestion`.`AnswerTypeId` = `AnswerType`.`AnswerTypeId`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `FileStore` AS `File`
ON
    `QBQuestion`.`FileId` = `File`.`ID`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `QBQuestionSkill` AS `QBQuestionSkills`
ON
    `QBQuestion`.`Id` = `QBQuestionSkills`.`QBQuestionId`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Skill` AS `QBQuestionSkills->Skill`
ON
    `QBQuestionSkills`.`SkillId` = `QBQuestionSkills->Skill`.`SkillId`
WHERE
    (
        `QBQuestion`.`QBQuestionSkills.Skill.Skill` LIKE '%python%' OR `QBQuestion`.`Text` LIKE '%python%'
    );
```

In the query, if you see, in Where clause you can notice `QBQuestion`.`QBQuestionSkills.Skill.Skill` Which is wrong.

I have tried to put like this (Notice the `$`):
`{ '$QBQuestionSkills.Skill.Skill$': { [Sequelize.Op.substring]: 'python' } }`

in this way it forms something like this:

```
SELECT
    `QBQuestion`.*,
    [..REDACTED..]
    `QBQuestionSkills->Skill`.`Category` AS `QBQuestionSkills.Skill.Category`,
    `QBQuestionSkills->Skill`.`Skill` AS `QBQuestionSkills.Skill.Skill`
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        `QBQuestion`.`Id`,
        `QBQuestion`.`Text`,
        `QBQuestion`.`DomainId`,
       [..REDACTED..]
        `AnswerType`.`AnswerTypeId` AS `AnswerType.AnswerTypeId`,
        `AnswerType`.`Name` AS `AnswerType.Name`
    FROM
        `QBQuestion` AS `QBQuestion`
    INNER JOIN `AnswerType` AS `AnswerType`
    ON
        `QBQuestion`.`AnswerTypeId` = `AnswerType`.`AnswerTypeId`
    WHERE
        (
            `QBQuestionSkills->Skill`.`Skill` LIKE '%python%' OR `QBQuestion`.`Text` LIKE '%python%'
        )
    ORDER BY
        `QBQuestion`.`Id`
    DESC
LIMIT 0,
100
) AS `QBQuestion`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `QuestionType` AS `QuestionType`
ON
    `QBQuestion`.`QuestionTypeId` = `QuestionType`.`QuestionTypeId`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `FileStore` AS `File`
ON
    `QBQuestion`.`FileId` = `File`.`ID`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `QBQuestionSkill` AS `QBQuestionSkills`
ON
    `QBQuestion`.`Id` = `QBQuestionSkills`.`QBQuestionId`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Skill` AS `QBQuestionSkills->Skill`
ON
    `QBQuestionSkills`.`SkillId` = `QBQuestionSkills->Skill`.`SkillId`
ORDER BY
    `QBQuestion`.`Id`
DESC
    ;
```

This gives me some error like this:
`sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'QBQuestionSkills->Skill.Skill' in 'where clause'",`

After all this, I see the first query is fairly simple, but I just want to filter with `Skill` instead of `QBQuestionSkills.Skill.Skill`.
Now, when I replace the same with `Skill`, it becomes something like this: `QBQuestion`.`Skill`
which is not present. instead `Skill` is present.

Does anyone have any idea on how to handle this?

basically what I feel is, when you querying a model with where clause, in SQL, it actually keeps the where like this: `Model`.`Field`, what I'm assuming will work for me is `Field` without the accompany of the `Model`.

Note: I could put where clause inside includes. but it should be with `Or` with other fields in the top level.

also, if there are some other recommendations or suggestions I'm all ears!